# Two nearly identical C++ functions being used to accomplish nearly the same task(find the average of lines of 25 numbers), yet only one is functional?

Tags: c++, xml

I am writing a program in C++ that is supposed to [locate 6 specific lines in an XML file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijYWZ.png), each of the 6 lines individually holding 25 numeric values, and then find the average of those 25 numeric values for each line separately and output that average to the console window and to an output file. Three of the 6 lines deal with voltage data, and the other three lines deal with Wattage data.

I've been able to find the average of each of the 3 wattage lines. However, I'm having continual issues whenever I try to find the average of each of the 3 voltage lines, despite the function to find the average of each of the 3 voltage lines being very similar to the working function that finds the average of each of the 3 wattage lines, the averages being output just aren't correct for the voltage lines(see screenshots).

Where is the point of fault for `void voltAvg();` that is resulting in incorrect output? I've been working on this project for ages and this is the single issue standing between me and a complete project and I've been agonizing over it for hours. Someone please lend me a hand! I would just like to extend a tremendous thank you in advance for taking the time to help me out!

Expected output:https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVIDT.jpg

Current Output: http://imgur.com/Unl2aLO

XML file: http://pastebin.com/5hMy9RzK

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <sstream>
void timestamps();
void voltAvg();
void wattAvg();
void electric();
using namespace std;
float sum; //global variable
ifstream infile;
ofstream outFile;

int main() {
outFile.open("Outputdata.txt");
infile.open("Groupproject.xml"); // Opens the XML file containing the information that is to be read
if (infile.fail())
{
    cout << "The file is not able to be located" << endl;
    system("Pause");
    exit(1);
}
electric();

infile.clear();
infile.seekg(0, ios::beg);

timestamps();

infile.clear();
infile.seekg(0, ios::beg);

voltAvg();

infile.clear();
infile.seekg(0, ios::beg);

wattAvg();



infile.close();
outFile.close();
system("pause");
return 0;
}

void electric() {
string fileinput;
regex electric_regex("electric_6[1-6]");
smatch electric_matches;



while (getline(infile, fileinput)) {  //Until the end of the file is reached, obtain each line


    if (regex_search(fileinput, electric_matches, electric_regex)) { // if regex_search is able to locate a line which has elements matching the regex expression "time_regex" output the located element

        cout << electric_matches[0] << endl;
        outFile << electric_matches[0] << endl;

    }

}
cout << "-------------------------------------------" << endl;
}

void timestamps() {
string fileinput;
regex time_regex("\\d\\d\\d\\d-\\d\\d-\\d\\d\\w\\d\\d:\\d\\d:\\d\\d\\.716Z");
smatch time_matches;



while (getline(infile, fileinput)) {  //Until the end of the file is reached, obtain each line


    if (regex_search(fileinput, time_matches, time_regex)) { // if regex_search is able to locate a line which has elements matching the regex expression "time_regex" output the located element

        cout << time_matches[0] << endl;
        outFile << time_matches[0] << endl;

    }

}
cout << "-------------------------------------------" << endl;
}

void voltAvg() {
float avevolt;
float dataValuesvolt;
int indexvolt;
string svolt;
string locateWordvolt;

getline(infile, svolt); //gets first line of file
indexvolt = svolt.find(' '); //finds first white space
locateWordvolt = svolt.substr(0, indexvolt); //cuts up line and assigns to locateWord
while (locateWordvolt != "<VoltAmpereReactiveTimeSeries")
{
    getline(infile, svolt);
    indexvolt = svolt.find(' ');
    locateWordvolt = svolt.substr(0, indexvolt);

}

infile.ignore(91, '\n'); // Ignores all of the stuff on the "<VoltAmpereReactiveTimeSeries" line and gets to the numbers on the subsequent line
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (int count = 0; count < 25; count++) //sums 25 voltage/wattage values
    {
        infile >> dataValuesvolt;//extract voltage data values from InFile
        sum += dataValuesvolt;
    }
    avevolt = sum / 25.0; //calculate the average voltage
    cout << "Average Voltage: " << avevolt << endl;//outputs ave on screen
    outFile << "Average Voltage: " << avevolt << endl; //Prints the average to out file
    sum = 0; // re-initialize sum 

    getline(infile, svolt); //gets first line of file
    indexvolt = svolt.find(' '); //finds first white space
    locateWordvolt = svolt.substr(0, indexvolt); //cuts up line and assigns to locateWord
    while (locateWordvolt != "<VoltAmpereReactiveTimeSeries")
    {
        getline(infile, svolt);
        indexvolt = svolt.find(' ');
        locateWordvolt = svolt.substr(0, indexvolt);

    }

}
}

void wattAvg() {
float ave;
float dataValues;
int index;
string s;
string locateWord;
getline(infile, s); //gets first line of file
index = s.find(' '); //finds first white space
locateWord = s.substr(0, index); //cuts up line and assigns to locateWord
while (locateWord != "<WattageTimeSeries")
{
    getline(infile, s);
    index = s.find(' ');
    locateWord = s.substr(0, index);

}
infile.ignore(0, '\n'); // Ignores all of the stuff on the "<WattageTimeSeries" line and gets to the numbers on the subsequent line

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (int count = 0; count < 25; count++) //sums 25 voltage/wattage values
    {

        infile >> dataValues;//extract wattage data values from InFile
        sum += dataValues;
    }
    ave = sum / 25.0; //calculate the average wattage
    cout << "Average Wattage: " << ave << endl;//outputs ave on screen
    outFile << "Average Wattage: " << ave << endl; //Prints the average to out file
    sum = 0; // re initialize sum 

    getline(infile, s); //gets first line of file
    index = s.find(' '); //finds first white space
    locateWord = s.substr(0, index); //cuts up line and assigns to locateWord
    while (locateWord != "<WattageTimeSeries")
    {
        getline(infile, s);
        index = s.find(' ');
        locateWord = s.substr(0, index);

    }

 }
}
```

Comment: A debugging suggestion:  Most likely the problem is reading the wrong numbers from the input file.  Right after `infile >> dataValuesvolt;` put in `cout << dataValuesvolt <<' ';` as a temporary diagnostic.  Knowing exactly which 25 numbers were read should help you figure out why.

Comment: @JSF I printed to console a series of `cout` statements to replicate what what the correct output should look like to make it easier for people helping me out to see what my goal is. The averages you see in the "correct" output form have all been checked by myself to be the averages I should be obtaining if my program were to be properly functioning. Unfortunately, as my program stands right now, I am only obtaining the correct averages for the 3 wattage lines. I've been pulling my hair out for the past 5 hours trying to find the issue, but I feel like I'm just running in hopeless circles.

Comment: @JSF I will try that out, thanks.

Comment: I don't understand the intent of the `infile.ignore(91, '\n'); ` line and think that is the bug.  Before that instruction, you already read the whole line that you think you are discarding with that operation, so I think you are really discarding the next line (discarding the data you want to read).

Comment: @JSF After implementing your temporary diagnostic, I get this: https://gyazo.com/63a4fcadbea9213728ef344ced40c8c0   I have no clue how the number `3899` is getting duplicated so frequently? Any ideas? Thanks for taking the time to try to help me by the way, I'm being driven up the wall by this program.

Comment: @JSF Okay, this is interesting. After removing `infile.ignore(91, '\n'); ` as you suggested along with the temporary diagnostic, now I am only obtaining the correct voltage values and no wattage values at all. Picture: https://gyazo.com/30f1aa86c73d9109cc61372ef1309197

Comment: On my screen, those two gyazo images are just black.  There is a hint of where the white text is supposed to be, but not nearly enough to guess what the white text was supposed to say.

Comment: @Sorry, I will upload them to imgur for you. Please don't leave me lol, you are my only hope .

Comment: But the obvious other bug is that you look for `"<VoltAmpereReactiveTimeSeries"` both before the first one and after each of the three, meaning a total of four times when it only appears 3 times in the input.

Comment: @JSF Picture from my 3rd comment: http://i.imgur.com/isTOuEi.jpg   Picture from my 4th comment: http://i.imgur.com/wRZOzQ2.jpg

Comment: @JSF How would I go about reducing my search for `< "VoltAmpereReactiveTimeSeries"`  from 4 to 3? I can't just remove the while loop inside the for loop without throwing a monkey wrench into my code.

Comment: Get rid of it from before the `for` loop and put it once **inside** the beginning of the `for` loop, so it occurs **once** before reading each voltage line.

Comment: @JSF HOLY CRAP, YOU RESOLVED THE ISSUE, THE CODE FULLY WORKS!! Words can not express how appreciative I am right now for your patience and persistence! Seeing a 100% functional solution put the biggest smile on my face, since I will now be able to finally go to sleep at 4 AM after burning the midnight oil fighting my code for the past 6 hours. Screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/f842abQ.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
float sum; //global variable
```

First, why a global variable? If you need the value outside the function, just return it instead of a void.
Second, sum is never initialised to 0, but then you do a sum += dataValuesvolt;. Whatever was in sum before you add something to it will still be there.

Also, this is outside the scope of this question, but if I were you, I would I have a close look at the structure of your code. For instance, your average functions are doing way too many things at the same time.

Comment: " Whatever was in sum before you add something to it will still be there." That is by design, since I want to store all 25 values then divide by 25 to find the average of those 25 values.

Comment: Yes, but you need to initialise it somewhere at 0. What is the value of sum before you add the first of your 25 values? It might be 0, but it's more likely to be something else, ie some rest of a previous variable not referenced anymore, but not erased either.

Comment: `sum` as a global is terrible style, but not a bug.  It is reliably zero before first used and then set back to zero **after** use, so it is zero before the next batch of 25.